# How to remove a character from a string only if it follows a number?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have several rows of data that are in address format, I want to remove the house number from each address.

So far I have been able to remove the number using:

```
<?php
$string = '25a Test Lane';
if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", $string)) {
  $string = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $string);
}
?>
```

$string then becomes 'a Test Lane' - but how would I go about removing 'a' as well?  Bearing in mind the 'a' could be any letter following a number. I'd want to remove any character that immediately follows the number (no space in between).

Comment: In this case, simply adding a character group for letters a-z with the `?` quantifier should probably do the job, `/[0-9]+[a-z]?/`

Comment: What result do you expect? '25 Test Lane' or ' Test Lane' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
trim(preg_replace("/\b\d+[a-zA-Z]*\b/", "", $string))
trim(preg_replace("/\b\d+[a-zA-Z]?\b/", "", $string))
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ip6g5r/1). **NOTE**: if you only want to allow a single letter after the number, replace `*` with `?` in `[a-zA-Z]*`.

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters
- `[a-zA-Z]?` - one or zero ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/64JJK):

```php
$string = '25a Test Lane';
$string = trim(preg_replace("/\b\d+[a-zA-Z]*\b/", "", $string));
echo $string;
// => Test Lane
```